# jQuery Validate Plugin Adds Inline Style to Errors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have an extremely basic example of this [here](http://jsbin.com/agexa3/4).  To replicate, try submitting the form, it will then alert you that the field is required.  Then fill in some text, then erase all the text.  You will see the error message jump down to the next line.

After inspecting with Firebug it shows that the plugin is adding `style="display: block"` inline on the element.  How can I prevent any inline styles from being generated on the element?  I know you can modify the .error class fro style, however the inline style it applies obviously trumps the applied class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `style="display: block"` via JavaScript is the only way to dynamically show and hide elements at run time. This is not really so bad as most inline styles. It's the same thing that happens when you call `$("#myElement").show()` in normal jQuery.

**Edit:** to follow up on getting the behavior you want, I went and edited your jsBin; if I did it right, the new version should be [here](http://jsbin.com/agexa3/11).

It became clear that the problem was that the behavior of `this.defaultShowErrors()` was to use jQuery's `.show()` method on the error list, which (as discussed above and in the comments) in this case will set an inline `display: block` style. Since we want `display: inline`, we need to modify `showErrors` like so:

```
showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
    this.defaultShowErrors();
    $.each(errorList, function (i, error) {
        $(error.element).css("display", "inline");
    });
}
```

This way, whenever the errors are hidden, then shown again, our custom `showErrors` function will trigger. They'll get set to `display: block` momentarily by `this.defaultShowErrors()`, but then we'll fix that and set them to `display: inline`.

Comment: This makes sense, however the problem is the display is block, so it drops it to the second line.  I want it to remain to the right of the text box.  How can I achieve this?  If it set display: inline, there would be no issue...

Comment: That's a bit tough... it's a problem I've run into. I think that if you set them to `display: inline` originally, e.g. in your CSS, and then call jQuery `hide()` on them, future calls to `show()` will use `inline`. Not 100% sure though...

Comment: Call hide on what?  I think I see what you are getting at but I haven't been able to get it.  Can you replicate it with the JS Bin example I posted?

Comment: Ooh I didn't see the jsBin link. Well why not just change `error.insertAfter(element);` to `error.insertAfter(element).css("display", "inline");`

Comment: I tried this here: http://jsbin.com/agexa3/8/ doing what you said and it doesn't appear to help.  Any other suggestions on this?  Seems like such a silly one.

Comment: `.show()` is *not* the same as adding `display: block;`, `block` is far from the only `display` style.

Comment: I didn't say it was the same thing; I said that it's the same thing as what happens when you call `.show()` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else I fixed this using the following "hack."  If there is a cleaner way, just let me know.

http://jsbin.com/agexa3/10/

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
                this.defaultShowErrors();
                $.each(errorList, function (i, error) {
                    $(error.element).next('span.error').css("display", "inline");
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution (Thanks Damilare and Domenic)

```
showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
     this.defaultShowErrors();
     $.each(errorList, function (i, error) {
          $(error.element).next('span.error').css("display", "inline");
     });
}
```

However, should this not work, check the structure. $(error.element) is the control that has error. ".next" is its following sibling. In my case this sibling was a  and its first child was the span.error tag.
Use for example this notation:

```
$(error.element).next().children(':first-child').css("display", "inline");
```